# Best way to redirect user to Login page on cache lost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to redirect user to login when cache is lost?
At moment I'm doing this:

```
if (Session["Id"] == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
}
```

But with this method, it put this code in every function, is there any other way to do this in the entire program? I tried search by doing this from web.config, but no results.

Comment: Ordinarily MVC takes care of this for you, if you're using the standard user management features.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about how you're managing authentication etc.

Comment: What type of authentication you are using?

Comment: Form-based authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Form-based authentication and permitting access to only authorised users then this could be achieved through making changes in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" name=".YourApplication" timeout="60" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

the loginUrl property tells the server where to direct the user if he is not logged in, and the defaultUrl property tells the server where to direct him after the user is logged.

the deny users="?" tells the server to deny any user that is not authenticated and directs him to the loginUrl page

In the codebehind of the login page, you need something like this after you check the credentials inserted:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName.Text, True)
```

[Reference](https://forums.asp.net/t/2022284.aspx?Redirect%20to%20login%20page%20if%20not%20logged%20in%20)

Comment: Yes, it's Form-based. I have used the authorization tag on my Intranet software (auto-login from AD, don't ask for user/password) and it works, but when I need a post code to validate the user/password it returns "Access denied" and don't reach the post function to verify the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string GlobalAuthKey = "GlobalAuthTime";
```

You can insert all auth user info in authList.

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(GlobalAuthKey, authList);
```

Then Get cache :

```
var authList = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(GlobalAuthKey) as List<AuthInfo> ?? new 
 List<AuthInfo>();
```

After that you check this specific user login info,and you force your user by this desire condition.Hopefully You understand.